# Proper setting of the Umbraco distributedCall setting (multi-server cluster setting)

Tags: iis, umbraco, cluster-computing

We have a server setup where we have 2 web servers for our Umbraco site:

1 is the "editor". This is where people add content. This can serve pages back to the editors, but the public never sees this.

2 are the "web servers". These serve content to the public. They NEVER allow editing.

Normally, we have had them as 2 servers - one serves to the public AND allows editing, the other just serves to the public.

Whats the correct setup for the distributedCall config option? I'd normally list all nodes in the cluster, but do I need to list the editor one, in this case? Or just the two "public" ones? I assume that it does something like:

commit the publish locally
call server A in the list
call server B in the list

which would mean I dont need to list the editor in the list (Which I'd rather not do)

[Umbraco 4.7 BTW]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own questions again. Sigh.

Ended up "just doing it" on our live site. In the end:

Editing server: has distributedcall turned on. points to both other nodes AND itself.

2 web nodes: have distributedcall turned OFF.

I had the 2 nodes turned on, but they tended to call back on themselves, which was problematic.

Fixed.